# UFO problems.... meaby misconfiguration... but do not understad

Tags: php, database, testing, zend-framework2

I have been working 7 day in this issue....In a PHP (zend frameworks 2) 
I try to read one database but it redirects me to another database.

I have an MAIN aplication in my subdomain http://sigi.zzzzzz.com using the user: AAAAAAAA and password Bbbbbbbbb$. The MAIN aplication is working ok

And i am working on a TEST version of the same application http://pruebasigi.zzzzzz.com/ using the same User and pasword.

In MAIN aplication sigi.zzzzzz.com has defined open the database 'DataBase_sigi' only in this files (

/.../sigi.zzzzzz.com/config/autoload/local.php
/.../sigi.zzzzzz.com/config/autoload/global.php
)

and in TEST Aplication pruebasigi.zzzzzz.com has defined open only the database TEST 'DataBase_prusigi' only in this files (

/.../pruebasigi.zzzzzz.com/config/autoload/local.php
/.../pruebasigi.zzzzzz.com/config/autoload/global.php
)

Only in these two files is defined the working database of this application as you know in ZF2.

The test database (DataBase_pruebasigi) was made as a copy of the original (DataBase_sigi).

why working with the TEST application reads the MAIN database and not the TEST database???

But when I write / update information in the TEST database (DataBase_pruebasigi ) write in the TEST database, but still reading from the MAIN Database (DataBase_sigi) ??

When i delete the MAIN Database (DataBase_sigi) and use the  TEST Aplication give me a big error.....

Thanks your help...

Comment: Hi Jorge. You might want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Zabop.... english is not my first languaje....

Comment: I open a database but show me information of other database...

Comment: code code code, where is the code? What did you try? What problems did you encounter? Show us the config you created in `local.php` and `global.php`. Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the files of TEST Aplication:
Directori:   **pruebasigi.aaaaaaaaaaaa.com**/config/autoload
File: **local.php**

```
//config/autoload/local.php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => '**Aaaaaaaaaaaa**',
        'password' => '**Bbbbbbbbbbbbb!**',
        'dbname'   => '**basedatos_pruebasigi**',
    ),
);
```

File : **global.php**

```
return array(
    "service_manager" => array(
        "factories" => array(
            "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter" => "Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory"
        )
    ),
    "db" => array(
        "username" => "**Aaaaaaaaaaaa**",
        "password" => "**Bbbbbbbbbbbbb**!",
        "driver" => "Pdo",
        "dsn" => "mysql:dbname=**basedatos_pruebasigi**;host:localhost",
        "driver_options" => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
        )
    ),
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    'session' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
            'options' => array(
                'use_cookies' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
                'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

An this is the code of the ORIGINAL Aplication...
Directori:   **sigi.aaaaaaaaaaaa.com**/config/autoload
file: **local.php**

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        // for primary db adapter that called
        // by $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
        'username' => '**Aaaaaaaaaaaa**',
        'password' => '**Bbbbbbbbbbb!**',
        // to allow other adapter to be called by
        // $sm->get('db1') or $sm->get('db2') based on the adapters config.
        'adapters' => array(
            'db1' => array(
                'username' => 'basedatos_foro',
                'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

File: **global.php**

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        //this is for primary adapter....
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=**basedatos_sigi**;host=localhost',
        'driver_options'  => array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'' ),     
        //other adapter when it needed...
        'adapters' => array(
            'db1' => array(
                'driver' => 'Pdo',
                'dsn'    => 'mysql:dbname=basedatos_foro;host=localhost',
                'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',),
        'abstract_factories' => array('Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',),
    ),
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    'session' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
            'options' => array(
                'use_cookies' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
                'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: So, this solved it then? If so, please mark as answer. If not, then you should remove this answer and edit this into the question....